# Checkbox in the first row of datagrivew does not respond to click (does not check and un check)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms window with three tabs. All the three tabs have datagridviews. In first 2 tabs the datgridview is in virtual mode.
While the last tabs datagridview is databound. All these DataGrids have checkbox column(column0). 
On 1 machine the checkbox in the row0 does not get checked or unchecked. 
Sorting the datagridview does not help either even though there is new data in row0 the checkbox does not respond.
This happens in all 3 datagridviews.

It appears checkbox is not changing state upon mouse click however pressing space on the checkbox of row0 does check it.

Cannot understand what is the issue! help

I tried commenting the events and launched the exe. The issue still persists. I commented the below events 1 at a time and ran the exe.
The issue still persists. I have captured a logs. 
CellFormatting
CellMouseDown
CellMouseEnter
CellPainting
CellValueChanged
CellValueNeeded
CellValuePushed
ColumnHeaderMouseClick
CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged 
DataError

This is the log of mouse click on Row 0 Column 0:

dataGridContactAndGroups_CellMouseDown  RowIndex 0 ColumnIndex 0
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False

This is the log of mouse click on Row 1 Column 0:

dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellMouseDown CHECKBOX ISSUE RowIndex 1 ColumnIndex 0
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged CHECKBOX ISSUE Dirty Cell is Row 1 Column 0
dataGridContactAndGroups_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged  Is cell dirty?  True
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValuePushed CHECKBOX ISSUE Before if RowIndex1 ColumnIndex 0
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValuePushed CHECKBOX ISSUE RowIndex1 ColumnIndex 7 Selected Value True
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueChanged CHECKBOX ISSUE RowIndex 1 ColumnIndex 0
dataGridContactAndGroups_CellValueNeeded  Row 0 Column 0 checkvalue False
dataGridContactAndGroups_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged CHECKBOX ISSUE Dirty Cell is Row 1 Column 0

If you notice after CellMouseDown in Row 1 Column 0. CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, CellValuePushed & CellValueChanged have been fired
where as in Row 0 Column 0 these events have not fired.

Also i want to mention we are using wienfenlou docking control within a docked window these datagrids are placed

Comment: Are you sure that this happens only on one machine? If yes what are the differences between these machines? There is any kind of code that handles this click event? If yes do you mind to show it?

Comment: *Cannot understand what is the* **Problem** either! You should include some could to clarify the question

Comment: @Steve Both the machines run win 7, similar hardware. The application uses .NET 3.5.  **I am not sure what else to look for!!**

We are not handling the click events. For the virtual mode grids the events that are being handled are CellValuePushed, CellMouseDown, CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, CellValueNeeded,CellValueChanged,CellFormatting. While in databound grid has CellValueChanged & CellFormatting events handled.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but for anyone with the same problem try increasing the row height.

For to me unknown reasons the row height in DataGridView can cause checkboxes to not show (for me at row height 20 and lower)
and also for all of them to work except the first one ( at row height 24 and lower).

If anyone knows why this works, please let me know.